# Angular seterrors changes when the value of the control changes

Tags: angular

In my html I want to do something like this

```
[class.text-danger]="form.controls.entries.errors?.doesNotMatchDefaultEntries"
```

For now if I hard code the values in my ngOnInit as below the text is shown red works but as soon as I change the value of the control (in the front end) the text changes to black and does not stay red. This there any way of keeping the errors in the control?

```
this.form.controls.entries.setErrors({'doesNotMatchDefaultEntries': true});
```

I have added a Validator function as below

```
export function forbiddenValidator(): ValidatorFn {
 return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const forbidden = true;
    return forbidden ? {'doesNotMatchDefaultEntries': true} : null;
 };
}
```

In the OnInit changed code to

```
    this.form.controls.entries.setValidators([forbiddenValidator]);
    this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
```

Still does not work

Comment: You are setting another error in your `ts` file (`doesNotMatchSelectedTier`) and in the template you check for `doesNotMatchDefaultEntries`. Try matching these and see if the unwanted behavior persists.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I have fixed the example

Comment: Write a Validator Function for it. If the value fails the condition, the error will stay as long as the value is faulty.

Comment: @user2837961 can you add the implementation of your validator with your question?

Comment: Please see my updated question